# mecab-python3 をインストールする上での swig コマンドの必要性

Tags: python3, macos, mecab

私は現在以下のようにコマンドで mecab-python3 をインストールしようとしているのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。
これは swig をインストールすれば、解決するという意味でしょうか...?
もし、そうでなければ mecab-python3 をインストールする上での対処法を教えて頂けると助かります。

コマンド

```
$ pip install mecab-python3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mecab-python3 0.996.1のリリースからswigが必要なようですので、お使いの環境に合わせて事前にインストールしてください。

[mecab-python3 0.996.1](https://pypi.org/project/mecab-python3/0.996.1/)

> You must have mecab and **swig** installed before running setup.py.
>   (setup.pyを実行するには、事前にmecabとswigがインストールされている必要があります。)

---

以下蛇足

> swigをインストールすれば、解決するという意味でしょうか

手元で試せるものは、まず自分で試してみましょう。結果を見てわからないことがあれば改めて質問すべきかなと思います。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。アドバイスに感謝です。今後も精進させて頂きますのでよろしくお願い致します。